# How do I call the functions of the imported library from my function?

Tags: python

While trying to get information from some web pages using BeautifulSoup, there are many overlapping codes, so I want to make it a function, but I want to call a function within `bs` such as `find_all` and `select`. How can I do it?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def test(url, function, *lst):
    
    result = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "lxml")
    result = soup.function(*lst)
    return

test('www', find_all)
test('www', select_one)
```

> NameError: name 'find_all' is not defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the function like (you may have to provide additional arguments)

```
test('www','find_all')
```

You can call the method "find_all" in the function like:

```
result = getattr(soup, function)(*lst)
```